# tkinter background image in Frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to put a background image in a Frame, this is the code that I'm trying to run without success.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root = tk.Tk()

F1 = Frame(root)
F1.grid(row=0)

photo = PhotoImage(file="sfondo.png")
label = Label(F1, image=photo)
label.image = photo
label.place(x=0, y=0)

b = tk.Button(label, text="Start")
b.grid(row=8, column=8)

root.mainloop()
```

If I run the code as this, only a little point in the top left corner is displayed (the frame without nothing in, even if I placed the label inside of it). If I replace the label parent with `root`, it displays the button with a little part of the image as backgound (only the perimeter of the button is colored for a few pixels). However what I want is a full displayed background image in the frame where I can put the widgets that I want.

I tried to with the place method as this and PIL module

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()

F1 = Frame(root)
F1.grid(row=0)
image = Image.open("sfondo.png")

render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
img = tk.Label(F1, image=render)
img.image = render
img.place(x=0, y=40)

b = tk.Button(img, text="Start")
b.grid(row=8, column=8)

root.mainloop()
```

Here more or less I'm having the same problems, if I set the parent of the label to `root`, the button is displayed with the perimeter coloured.
If I set the parent to `F1` nothing happens and in both cases if I set the parent as `root` and remove the button, the image is fully displayed.
But what I want is that the image is fully displayed in the frame and after diplay on the background image the widgets.

Answer (score 10):

You could put an image on a `Canvas`, and then place a `Button` on that by putting it inside a [Canvas window object](https://web.archive.org/web/20190428235412id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/create_window.html) which can hold any Tkinter widget.

Additional widgets can be added in a similar fashion, each inside its own `Canvas` window object (since they can hold only a single widget each). You can workaround that limitation by placing a `Frame` widget in the `Canvas` window, and then putting other widgets inside *it*.

Here's an example showing how to display a single `Button`:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk

IMAGE_PATH = 'sfondo.png'
WIDTH, HEIGTH = 200, 200

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(WIDTH, HEIGHT))

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGTH)
canvas.pack()

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(IMAGE_PATH).resize((WIDTH, HEIGTH), Image.ANTIALIAS))
canvas.background = img  # Keep a reference in case this code is put in a function.
bg = canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=tk.NW, image=img)

# Put a tkinter widget on the canvas.
button = tk.Button(root, text="Start")
button_window = canvas.create_window(10, 10, anchor=tk.NW, window=button)

root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot of sample code running]

#### Edit

While I don't know of a way to do it in `Frame` instead of a `Canvas`, you could derive your own `Frame` subclass to make adding multiple widgets easier. Here's what I mean:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk


class BkgrFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, file_path, width, height):
        super(BkgrFrame, self).__init__(parent, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=width, height=height)
        self.canvas.pack()

        pil_img = Image.open(file_path)
        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_img.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS))
        self.bg = self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=tk.NW, image=self.img)

    def add(self, widget, x, y):
        canvas_window = self.canvas.create_window(x, y, anchor=tk.NW, window=widget)
        return widget


if __name__ == '__main__':

    IMAGE_PATH = 'sfondo.png'
    WIDTH, HEIGTH = 350, 200

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(WIDTH, HEIGTH))

    bkrgframe = BkgrFrame(root, IMAGE_PATH, WIDTH, HEIGTH)
    bkrgframe.pack()

    # Put some tkinter widgets in the BkgrFrame.
    button1 = bkrgframe.add(tk.Button(root, text="Start"), 10, 10)
    button2 = bkrgframe.add(tk.Button(root, text="Continue"), 50, 10)

    root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image: screenshot showing two widget displayed on a frame with a background]

### Update

It recently dawned on me that there actually ***is*** a simpler way to do this than creating a custom `Frame` subclass as shown in my previous edit above. The trick is to `place()` a `Label` with image on it in the center of the parent `Frame` — you are then free to use other geometry managers like `pack()` and `grid()` as you normally would — as illustrated in the sample code below. Not only is it less complicated, it's also a more "natural" way of adding widgets than needing to call a non-standard method such as `add()`.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk


IMAGE_PATH = 'sfondo.png'
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 250, 150

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(WIDTH, HEIGHT))

# Display image on a Label widget.
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(IMAGE_PATH).resize((WIDTH, HEIGHT), Image.ANTIALIAS))
lbl = tk.Label(root, image=img)
lbl.img = img  # Keep a reference in case this code put is in a function.
lbl.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')  # Place label in center of parent.

# Add other tkinter widgets.
button = tk.Button(root, text="Start")
button.grid(row=0, column=0)
button = tk.Button(root, text="Continue")
button.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Result#2

[image: screenshot showing two widget displayed on a frame with a background using alternative method]

**P.S.** You can download a copy of the `sfondo.png` background image from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SRYZ.png).

Comment: there is a way to do it in `Frame` and not `Canvas`?

Comment: @user9994167: I don't think so — see **Edit** in my answer.