# Why tkinter is not showing both image and objects on the next frame?

Tags: python, tkinter

tkinter is either showing  image or showing labels on the next frame when I implemented it using a button and called both the functions via that button but it isn't showing both

when clicked on a button I want it to display image as a background on the next frame and the next frame should consist of objects also like labels or buttons

I created two functions, one for the image and the other for creating frame and displaying label on the next frame

Here is the code which I implemented:

```
import tkinter
w = tkinter.Tk()
w.geometry("1200x700")
w.resizable(False, False)
w.config(bg='#F4C430')
def imgbg():
    global img,img1
    img = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="stimage.png")
    img1 = tkinter.Label(image=img)
    img1.place(x=0, y=0)
    
def nextframe():
    global frame2
    frame2=tkinter.Frame()
    frame2.place(x=0,y=0,width=1200,height=700)
    label = tkinter.Label(frame2, text="this is second frame",fg='red')
    label.place(x=20, y=30)



bn=tkinter.Button(w,text='click',command=lambda :[nextframe(),imgbg()])
bn.place(x=50,y=50)
w.mainloop()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Still answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54253332/12621346)

Comment: You put the frame on top of the image and so the frame will cover the image.  You need to put the image inside the frame as well.

Answer (score 0):

To add both images and text to a label, you have to also pass the `compound` argument. It specifies which side the image is drawn to the text.

Syntax-

```
tkinter.Label(image = img, compound = LEFT, text = "Hello World!")
```

This will add your image to the left of your text.